# entity framework - n-tier - many to many - how to get list "where"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many, n-tier-architecture, navigation-properties

many to many class

[image]

in database my table is

[image]

[image]

[image]

I use EF6 and N-Tier and implement a generic data access layer from this [post](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/05/30/generic-dal-using-entity-framework/)

I want to give Lesson is in the Group ,I Use this Method to Get list in DAL

```
    public virtual IList<T> GetList(Func<T, bool> where, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
    {
        List<T> list;
        using (var context = new AzmaEntities())
        {
            IQueryable<T> dbQuery = context.Set<T>();
            foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
                dbQuery = dbQuery.Include<T, object>(navigationProperty);
            list = dbQuery
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Where(where)
                .ToList<T>();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

and in Business Layer :

```
    public IList<Lesson> GetLessonWhereGrpId(int grpId)
    {
        Group grp = new Group();
        GroupBLL grpbll = new GroupBLL();
        grp = grpbll.GetGroupById(grpId);

        return _LessonRepository.GetList(
            d => d.Group.Equals(grp)
            );
    }
```

when debugging , my code Generate this SQL query :

```
DECLARE @EntityKeyValue1 AS SQL_VARIANT;
SET @EntityKeyValue1 = Null;

SELECT 
    [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent2].[Ex_Id] AS [Ex_Id], 
    [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent2].[Factor] AS [Factor]
    FROM  [dbo].[LsnToGrp] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Group] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Grp_Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Lsn_Id] = @EntityKeyValue1
```

**This is not ture , I want to find Lesson is in the group**

> Find Lessons where Group Id is

Comment: Why do you use `d.Group.Equals(grp)`? It disguises the fact that you're comparing incompatible types (collection vs. instance). Change it into `d.Group == grp` to see what's wrong.

Comment: Try `d => d.Group.Select(x => x.Id).Contains(grpId)`

Comment: @GertArnold I changed But Sql Query Not chenge, and inner join `LsnToGrp` with `Group` and `Where Lsn_Id =`

Comment: @dotctor thank you, this solution work. please send as answer

Comment: @dotctor why in your solution EF, execute query per lesson is in the Lesson Table? is better solution to send one query to fetch data? (in this pattern n-tier layer)

Comment: What do  you mean by query per lesson?

Comment: @dotctor I save 4 lesson in my Table .When query Execute, ADO.net Send 5 request to DB . First select Lesson Table , then per record (lesson) is in table send Query. [link](https://s13.postimg.org/w05on42yv/image.png). Above Query

Comment: See the updated answer. @amirabdollahi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126115/discussion-between-amir-abdollahi-and-dotctor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check if groups related to that lesson contains the specified group id

```
public IList<Lesson> GetLessonWhereGrpId(int grpId)
{
    return _LessonRepository.GetList(
        d => d.Group.Any(x => x.Id == grpId)
        );
}
```

But why not getting lessons related to the specified group?

```
public IList<Lesson> GetLessonWhereGrpId(int grpId) 
{ 
    GroupBLL grpbll = new GroupBLL(); 
    grp = grpbll.GetGroupById(grpId, g => g.lesson); 

    return grp.lesson.ToList(); 
}
```